# Defining the original matrix when matrice's eigenvalues and eigenvectors are given

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need some clarification and possible advise for a troublesome situation.

Let's assume we have matrix in size $3 \times 3$. The matrix has some eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ that corresponds to eigenvector $v_1$ and another eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ that correponds to eigenvectors $v_2$ and $v_3$. In other words, we have two eigenspaces $E=(λ_1:A) = \operatorname{Span}(v_1)$ and $E=(λ_2:A) = \operatorname{Span}(v_2, v_3)$. **Now the job is to define the original matrix $A$.**

I know what to do, if I had three eigenvalues corresponding to each vector only once:
$A=QPQ^{-1}$ would hold clearly as $Q$ would be just $[v_1, v_2, v_3]$ and linearly independent and thus invertible, and $P$ would be a diagonal matrix with the main diagonal being $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3)$.

But what is the way to find $A$ when there are less eigenvalues than there are eigenvectors? The $P$ cannot clearly be reduced into $2 \times 2$ matrix where the diagonal is the two known eigenvalues $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2)$ because multiplication $QPQ^{-1}$ become impossible.

Or is the $P$ treated as $3 \times 3$ matrix the diagonal being $(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_2)$ because then the values on the $P$'s diagonal would correspond to the $Q$'s vectors $[v_1, v_2, v_3]$ and $QPQ^{-1}$ be possible.

*(Actually tried this, but sometimes the resulting $A$ had and didn't have the eigenvectors $[v_1, v_2, v_3]$, that in the first place were defining the $A$, but the eigenvalues always matched when finding the "to be defined" $A$'s eigenvalues. Why does this happen, like going bothways (eigens to $A$, from $A$ back to eigens) sometimes works but not always?)*

I see that there's a possibility to work backwards the $\det(A - \lambda I)=0$ route as the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are known, but that feels very tortuous way to find $A$ and there must be a shortcut or a rule that I am missing or misinterpreting.

Comment: There is no problem if there are less eigenvalues than the dimension of $A$, provided $A$ is [non-defective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) (i.e. it has enough independent eigenvectors). If an [eigenvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) has geometric and algebraic multiplicities both equal to $k$, then it will just appear $k$ times in the diagonal. If those multiplicities are not equal for some eigenvalue, then you are out of luck, the matrix is not diagonalizable, but here you have three independent eigenvectors.

Comment: The matrix $A = PQP^{-1}$, where 
$$
P = \bigl[ v_1, v_2, v_3 \bigr] 
\quad\text{and}\quad 
Q = \operatorname{diag}(\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_2)
$$ 
will have eigenvector $v_1$ of eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ and eigenvectors $v_2$ and $v_3$ of eigenvalue $\lambda_2$. It doesn’t matter that the eigenvectors are not distinct.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut To confirm: so given what I wrote in second paragraph, where the eigenspaces are defined, I can do what I proposed in the 5th paragraph: make the $P$'s diagonal have 2 times the $λ_2$ and once the $λ_1$

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @SammyBlack thank's for clarification, I guess I made some algebraic error on paper.

Comment: Note that there are infinitely many eigenvectors. When there is an eigenvalue with geometric multiplicity $k>1$, two sets of eigenvectors are not necessarily pairwise collinear (you may "rotate" a basis of eigenvectors for the same eigenvalue, for instance). Therefore it's not a problem if from $Q$ and $P$ (with your notation) you compute $A$, then compute again eigenvectors and they are different.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut thanks for this mention. I remembered that I could do some multiplication with constants and eigen stuff but messed up where. Tried to multiply the eigenvalues, which didn't turn out well, because it's incorrect.

Comment: You have to think of the eigen**space** associated to a given eigenvalue. Then the choice of basis for this eigenspace (i.e. a set of linearly independent eigenvectors associated with this eigenvalue) is irrelevant.